# Windows 10 very slow, audio stutter, slow file explorer, lagging

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance, windows-explorer, kernel

I've got a new PC with windows 10. i5 - 16GB ram - 256GB SSD.
Should be fast enough and I think it was in the beginning, but now I have quite some trouble and a slow and sluggish pc. Also audio stutter, pops and lagging when CPU is high. I did many things as provided in answers on this and other sites, but so far no luck.

I downloaded WhySoSlow and one thing that really stands out is the slow Kernel Responsiveness and slow App Responsiveness. I think it is way to slow, am I right?

This is when doing a normal task like browsing or playing some youtube:

[whysoslow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9oYq.jpg)

Also the file explorer is really slow, every click the directory takes about 2 seconds to load.

The latest upgrade I did was add a Nvidia GT710 so I could use 2 monitors. I suspect it has to do with something, but I removed the GPU to test, but this seems to make no difference.

This machine is driving me crazy, can't normally work on it as fast as I would like to. How to tackle this problem?

Comment: First check the task manager to see which processes eat up CPU and RAM. Resource Monitor is also a good start to look for problems. If you have a spare HD you could install a clean Windows to check if it's a hardware issue but I expect it to be 3rd party software/bloat-ware/male-ware.

Comment: If it were me, I would run Process Explorer as Administrator (it is a free download from Microsoft). I would look at the processes that are using the most CPU, dbl+click on each and examine the "threads" tab, find the process or library that is taking the most time, and then google that process to get a sense of what it is. If it is software I don't need, I'd remove it to see if it resolves the issue. If it is a driver, I might temporarily disable the device. I did this recently on a friend's laptop and it was an intel user-mode driver for CPU throttling that was, using around 30%

Comment: Ugh, CPU throttling was on?! Sure I did put this on 100% already, could this go back to a lower value when I was switching between energy modes to test? Glad I did checked it because you say so, this speed up the machine already quite a bit! But still not as fast as it should? For example, when I click File Explorer it takes 5 seconds to load. When I click a dir, first blank, then when loaded, it takes about 2 seconds. When resizing the file explorer it's lagging about 1 second. Is this normal for windows 10? Should I just accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by high DPC latency. This somehow drags the whole computer down.

When running LatencyMon, I got numbers up to 5000uS sometimes. Large spikes with Realtek Lan and Nvidia GT videocard drivers especially.

I tried so many things, but the one thing that seems to fix it was running this in cmd (run as administrator):

**bcdedit /deletevalue useplatformclock**

Then hard restart your PC.

Now in LatencyMon there are only 1 or 2 green bars and 60uS idle is normal and 400uS when heavy work. The difference is night and day! The PC is lightning fast again. File explorer too. Feels like 100 times faster. Even with full energy saving options and heavy CPU throttling, still so much faster. I'm very happy with this, hope it could be a help for someone in the future too.

Interesting thing, before when the PC was idle, the CPU was about 20-30% in use. Now it is only 1-2%. It's almost like I have a ton of cores more now.

The other things that might be involved:

- Disable High Precision Event Timer in Device manager -> System devices
- In the BIOS set the PCI16x slot of the GPU to Gen3, however it does not matter if I put it back to auto later again
- Installed MSI afterburner. Then did a little overclocking en then reset it back to default value. Later uninstalled it. Not sure, but it could have reset something somehow on the Nvidia card.
- Updated BIOS
- Update all drivers
- Set windows virtual memory to 3GB fixed, min and max

Because when I rollback the useplatformclock command that worked for me, it is slow again, high DPC latency again, but not as slow as it was, just about half of it. If you want to rollback the command btw, you can use: *bcdedit /set useplatformclock true*

**update:**
I found another setting that I was able to reproduce that cause very high latency for the Realtek network lan device:

- Go to device manager -> networkadapters -> Realtek PCIe... double click for properties. Go to tab Advanced. Set 'Energy Efficient Ethernet' to disabled. I have this property twice somehow, so both disable them. Also disabled the property 'Green ethernet'. The LAN cause no latency anymore after this.

Comment: I am having the same exact problem, I have Nvidia GTX 745.  LatencyMon shows super high numbers >100,000 initially. I read some articles online and uninstalled the Nvidia HD Audio driver and now it drops down to <20,000. But still I have  slow Kernel Responsiveness and slow App Responsiveness through WhySoSlow app. TCP/IP driver shows DPC routine time >40,000 now.

Comment: This is fascinating to me as I'm fighting something similar but the latency is such that DPC monitoring via Resplendence LatencyMon is not detecting it.