# Windows 10 very slow especially when opening web browsers

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, browser, desktop-computer

My `Windows 10 desktop` is super slow when opening web browsers (such as yahoo.com). It takes about 8-10 seconds to fully load the page and slows down the entire OS while loading. If I am playing any music in the background, as soon as the browser is launched, it lags/slows down and even freezes sometimes until the page is fully loaded.

The task manager shows very high CPU activity (**70%-90%**)  when the webpage is loading. Tried restarting/ shutting down the PC multiple times with no luck. I leave the PC on for several weeks without shutting down. So may be the clutter/cache has been filled. Tried cleaning the OS (**CCleaner**) and it removed pretty much all temp/cache files/history  and so on, but still no luck. It used to work back in the days but not anymore.

Once I forced shutdown the PC while OS was running (press and hold power button for 5 seconds), that fixed the problem on the next time the OS loaded. Everything became fast and normal, but back to same old situation after leaving PC on for few days as usual.

So apparently there is some kind of caching happening somewhere that's using up all the memory and not getting reset even after a regular shutdown/restart. My virtual memory is set to **16GB**. RAM is 16GB as well.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated. I scanned for adware/malware and it's all clean.
My only option is to reinstall the OS now as I cant figure what's holding up the memory.

*I have a Windows 10 laptop which doesn't have this problem.  So its not the OS but some settings or configurations or maybe some installed apps?*

**UPDATE**

This link is exactly what I am experiencing. It might be related to the NVidia driver or some other driver incompatabilty with the OS.

[Slow Win10 PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1584203/windows-10-very-slow-audio-stutter-slow-file-explorer-lagging?rq=1)

[Extremely high DPC Latency from Directx Graphics Kerne](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dpc-routines-executed-too-long-popping-and/bd65116d-9d8d-4900-8863-96023d5629a5)

Modified power settings to use `High Performance` over energy consumption, reboot and now it appears to be normal with no delay/lag. But I'm sure it will come back to be slow again in few days. :(

Comment: Make sure you are not trying to open browsers with lots of tabs opening at the same time. Close tabs before closing the browser(s)

Comment: @John- No that's not the case, I have only one tab open. It affects other browsers as well. As I stated in my post, once I force reboot the PC, everything speeds up even with multiple browser tabs open. So it has to be something else using up all the memory/cache or whatever.

Comment: There could be numerous reasons for slowness.  Try running DISM and SFC to see if that helps.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Check the SMART attributes of the disk. If you don't have an app for this then use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) - if all the attributes are marked "Good" then run `chkdsk`.

Comment: @John- completed DISM.exe test, but no result, still slow.

Comment: @harrymc - SMART attributes are GOOD.

Comment: @yonikawa Have you tried starting your browser of choice in its safe mode?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - now its back to normal, I will try it next time it happens.

Comment: The issue is back again, I have to hard reset it every time it slows down and it fixes the problem. Not sure whats an ideal fix will be :(

Comment: @yonikawa Another thing to try is restarting the router.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I dont think its router, as it happens only on my Win10 PC. Also I had to hard reset the PC to fix the problem. Seems like its the nvidia graphics driver or some other hardware/driver related issue. Others have experienced the same issue as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Seems like its my nvidia graphics card causing the problem, every time I hard boot my PC, it speeds up for several hours or sometimes days and eventually slows down again.